Android Studio Java - Drawer cannot be clicked, but can be navigated with arrow keys
I am completely new to Java and Android development and I have encountered a problem, where the side drawer cannot be clicked with a mouse on the Android Studio emulator nor can it be clicked on my phone when I download the app. Additionally I can't even get firebase to display the Name and Surname on the drawer. Below are all files I am using to make this drawer:
nav_menu.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn = "navigation_view">

    <group
        android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/baseline_home_24"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:title="@string/studia"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_ustawienia"
            android:icon="@drawable/baseline_settings_24"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:title="@string/ustawienia"
            />




    </group>
    <item
        android:title="">

        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_wyloguj"
                android:icon="@drawable/baseline_logout_24"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:title="@string/wyloguj"

                />
        </menu>

    </item>

</menu>

activity_strona_glowma.xml (activity_main_page.xml):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    tools:context=".StronaGlowna">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:background="@color/ocenusowski"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/ocenusowski"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/ocenusowski"/>



    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
            app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="50dp">

            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"

                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />

        </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="93dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_add_24"
            app:maxImageSize="40dp"
            app:tint="@color/ocenusowski" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

And a fragment of StronaGlowna.java (MainPage.java):
bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        drawerLayout=findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);


        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open_nav,
                R.string.close_nav);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);
        }

        replaceFragment(new HomeFragment());

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    replaceFragment(new HomeFragment());
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_ustawienia:
                    replaceFragment(new SettingsFragment());
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_wyloguj:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Logowanie.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    break;
            }
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        });

        bottomNavigationView.setBackground(null);
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.StronaGlowna:
                    replaceFragment(new HomeFragment());
                    break;
                case R.id.Statystyki:
                    replaceFragment(new StatystykiFragment());
                    break;
                case R.id.Wydarzenia:
                    replaceFragment(new WydarzeniaFragment());
                    break;
                case R.id.Edycja:
                    replaceFragment(new EdycjaFragment());
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        });

        fab.setOnClickListener(view -> showBottomDialog());
    }

I have tried using many tutorials available online resulting in spaghetti code, I tried experimenting with onclicklisteners and other things but none have worked and I am at a loss.

Do other clicks work on the screen?
